# Regex to find emoticon with in the string

Tags: c#, emoji, shortcut

As of my question, is there any regex to find whether the string contains any short cut emoji like
:-) ,:-( .

I have tried googling but I found all the regex related to unified code for the emoji but not for finding the shortcut of emoji.

Comment: `:-)` is not an emoji (i.e. a Unicode ideogram) but is actually an "emoticon".

Comment: Thank you for letting me know :-) @Dai, Is there any regex for finding emoticon within the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex to [find Western-style Latin punctuation emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#Western-style) in left-top orientation. Use it in case-insensitive mode.

```
>?[\:\;X][\-=]*[3\)D\(>sp}]
```

It matches these, for example:

```
:-)

XD

;)

:3

;-)

>:3

:==3
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/XKJCwH/1

For matching right-top oriented emoticons you'll want to reverse the regex, but you'll also want to amend it to match emoticons like `P:` (derp) and `D:` (shock).